# How to view the log of all commands?

Tags: unix, logging, github, git-bash

I'm trying to view all commands that I've entered into the unix environment in my Git Bash.

So I'm not trying to view the list of possible commands for Git Hub. Neither am I trying to view the logs for pushes and pulls.

I just want to view what I entered in the command line. This is because I recently encountered a connection problem in which I couldn't push or pull from my git. It just happened suddenly. One minute ago, I was still pushing and pulling perfectly.

Then, someone helped me to resolve it via the command prompt in git bash.

Right now, my friend has the same problem. So I'm looking for the command logs in hopes that it will solve his problem too.

Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this with `cat $HISTFILE`.

Bash by default stores the last 500 commands in a history file, most likely  called ~/.bash_history. This file is in the variable $HISTFILE (and the size is in $HISTFILESIZE). You can get the path to the history file with `echo $HISTFILE`.

Comment: Weird. The .bash_history file that I have only has the past 111 lines from a few days ago. It does not have any of the commands I entered just now. Is there any other log file?

Comment: Bash writes this file when it terminates. So the commands of the actual session are invisible.

Comment: Note that 'history -a' will write the current session's history to the history file.

Comment: @Rudi It also does not have the commands I entered during the days between "a few days ago" and the time I commented. Git bash was closed, but the history wasn't updated. Earlier history is also missing :( Do you know how I can retrieve those histories that are currently missing?

Comment: obviously using cat $HISTFILE |grep WhateverYoureLookingFor is very helpful too.

Comment: @Peddler you can alo just use `grep WhateverYoureLookingFor $HISTFILE` for that job.

Comment: Interesting. My `$HISTFILE` is actually a file with a random name in `~/.zsh_sessions/` directory. That explains why the newest command where never recorded to `.zsh_history`

Answer (score 13):

```
history 1
```

This will display all entries in History starting at line 1.

Answer (score 9):

If you are still in the shell a quick way to see your recent session command history is the command:

```
$ history
```

Very handy for the scenario mentioned in the question, i.e. a colleague has typed some commands quickly in your session and you want to go back and have a closer look at them.

Comment: This is nice because it prints the command dates in a human-readable format.

Comment: This will only show the last 16 commands – `history 1` as suggested by @r-m will show all lines.

Answer (score 0):

**history n** is the command n is the number of lines to show, i,e **history 50** ,  it will show last 50 commands