# bash (or zsh) HISTSIZE vs. HISTFILESIZE?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

What is the difference in `HISTSIZE` vs. `HISTFILESIZE`?

They are used to extend bash history beyond the default 500 lines.

There seems to be a lack of clarity here and in other forums about why they are both needed. ([Example 1](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/191301-histsize-histfilesize.html), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401898/linux-history-command/10401951#10401951), [Example 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17587)).

Is this the same for zsh?

Comment: It's indeed ridiculous how unclear most blog posts are about this difference, even [from redhat](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/history-command).

Answer (score 399, accepted):

### Short answer:

`HISTSIZE` is the number of lines or commands that are stored in memory in a history list while your bash session is ongoing.

`HISTFILESIZE` is the number of lines or commands that (a) are allowed in the history file at startup time of a session, and (b) are stored in the history file at the end of your bash session for use in future sessions.

Notice the distinction between `file`: on disk - and `list`: in memory.

(NOTE: as noted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529975/583834), in zsh `HISTFILESIZE` should be `SAVEHIST`)

### Long answer:

All the info above + some examples:

**Example 1**:
`HISTFILESIZE=10` and `HISTSIZE=10`

1. You start your session.
2. Your HISTFILE (file that stores your bash command history), is truncated to contain HISTFILESIZE=10 lines.
3. You write 50 lines.
4. At the end of your 50 commands, only commands 41 to 50 are in your history list, whose size is determined by HISTSIZE=10.
5. You end your session.
6. Assuming `histappend` is not enabled, commands 41 to 50 are saved to your HISTFILE which now has the 10 commands it held at the beginning plus the 10 newly written commands.
7. Your HISTFILE is truncated to contain HISTFILESIZE=10 lines.
8. You now have 10 commands in your history - the last 10 that you just typed in the session you just finished.
9. When you start a new session, you start over at step 1 with a HISTFILE of HISTFILESIZE=10.

**Example 2**:
`HISTFILESIZE=10` and `HISTSIZE=5`

1. You start your session.
2. Your HISTFILE (file that stores your bash command history), is truncated to contain at most HISTFILESIZE=10 lines.
3. You write 50 lines.
4. At the end of your 50 commands, only commands 46 to 50 are in your history list, whose size is determined by HISTSIZE=5.
5. You end your session.
6. Assuming `histappend` is not enabled, commands 46 to 50 are saved to your HISTFILE which now has the 10 commands it held at the beginning plus the 5 newly written commands.
7. Your HISTFILE is truncated to contain HISTFILESIZE=10 lines.
8. You now have 10 commands in your history - 5 from a previous session and the last 5 that you just typed in the session you just finished.
9. When you start a new session, you start over at step 1 with a HISTFILE of HISTFILESIZE=10.

**Example 3**:
`HISTFILESIZE=5` and `HISTSIZE=10`

1. You start your session.
2. Your HISTFILE (file that stores your bash command history), is truncated to contain at most HISTFILESIZE=5 lines.
3. You write 50 lines.
4. At the end of your 50 commands, only commands 41 to 50 are in your history list, whose size is determined by HISTSIZE=10.
5. You end your session.
6. Assuming `histappend` is not enabled, commands 41 to 50 are saved to your HISTFILE which now has the 5 commands it held at the beginning plus the 10 newly written commands.
7. Your HISTFILE is truncated to contain HISTFILESIZE=5 lines.
8. You now have 5 commands in your history - the last 5 that you just typed in the session you just finished.
9. When you start a new session, you start over at step 1 with a HISTFILE of HISTFILESIZE=5.

Info from [elixir_sinari](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/191301-histsize-histfilesize.html):

> The history "file" is not updated as you type the commands. The
> commands get stored in a "list" separately (accessed by the history
> command). The number of these stored commands is controlled by
> HISTSIZE  value. When the shell (interactive) exits, the last
> $HISTSIZE  lines are copied/appended to  $HISTFILE  from that "list".
> If  HISTFILESIZE  is set, then after this operation, it is ensured
> that only  $HISTFILESIZE  lines (latest) exist in  $HISTFILE . And
> when the shell starts, the "list" is initialized from  $HISTFILE  up to
> a maximum of  $HISTSIZE  commands.

And from the `man bash` page:

> The  value
> of  the  HISTSIZE  variable  is used as the number of commands to save in a history list.  The text of the last HISTSIZE commands
> (default 500) is saved.  (...)
>
> On  startup,  the  history  is initialized from the file named by the variable HISTFILE (default ~/.bash_history).  The file named by
> the value of HISTFILE is
> truncated, if necessary, to contain no more than the number of lines specified by the value of HISTFILESIZE.  (...)  When an interactive shell exits, the last $HISTSIZE lines
> are copied from  the  history
> list to $HISTFILE.  If the histappend shell option is enabled (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below), the
> lines are appended to the
> history file, otherwise the history file is overwritten.  If HISTFILE is unset, or if the history file is unwritable, the history
> is not saved. (...)  After saving the history, the
> history file  is  truncated
> to contain no more than HISTFILESIZE lines.  If HISTFILESIZE is not set, no truncation is performed.

Comment: +1 This answer is impressively thorough! A bit too much though, I think. Most people won't reach the end of it. I think you should consider summarizing it

Comment: @slezica I disagree with the second part of your comment: I reached the end of it and I can say that every bit of information in the answer is useful. The fact that some people are too lazy to read a few lines shouldn't justify removing useful information for the others.

Comment: @Bastien assuming you are a bullet point parser, you will have no difficulties reading this.

Comment: Look, my hard drive is 1 TB and largely empty, and I have gobs of idle CPU cycles and RAM, and I want to save as much bash history as reasonably possible -- so when I need to look up that stupid command I haven't run in two years, I know it's in my bash history. To make it more concrete, let's say up to 50 MB of bash history. What values do you recommend?

Comment: Amazing answer! @arturomp, do you know about the command history widget/UI in iTerm2 shell integration's toolbelt? Does it get the history from the default history file (like .bash_history), or does it store the history itself someplace else? There's a feature where if you option+double click on a command in the widget it enters a cd + working directory at the time you executed it on the cli. I don't see that information being stored in .bash_history so I was curious where it is coming from! I created a question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47373577/5042013. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew sorry, don't know it!

Comment: *HISTFILESIZE=10 and HISTSIZE=10* – choosing *the same value* for two different variables does not really help when you try to show the difference between them. Considering that there are 10, 5 and 5, 10 cases shown later in the answer this one – 10, 10 – should be deleted.

Comment: @CivFan You might read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history and https://superuser.com/questions/137438/how-to-unlimited-bash-shell-history

Comment: Here's my tiny contribution: So that multiple terminals (ie `tmux`, etc) can see the history of other terminals, you have to press `enter` key once so that `PROMPT_COMMAND` gets executed and re-load the history

Comment: Is there any point in setting `HISTFILESIZE` greater than `HISTSIZE`? If we keep a larger history in the file than in memory, will that larger history ever be used by `bash`?

Comment: @joeytwiddle after having looked at example 2, have you tried this on your machine?

Comment: Fantastic answer! To clarify one thing that threw me off though, at the end of examples 1 and 2, when it says *When you start a new session, you start over at 1 with a HISTFILE of HISTFILESIZE=...*, what it means is (as it says at the end of example 3) *When you start a new session, you start over at **step** 1 with a HISTFILE of HISTFILESIZE=...* -- I spent ages stuck on that line, trying to figure out if it was saying that one of the *HIST* variables has its value reduced to 1 at startup for some reason. I'd edit it myself, but unfortunately it says the edit queue is full.

Comment: "*Assuming `histappend` is not enabled, [...] your HISTFILE [...] now has the 10 commands it held at the beginning plus the 10 newly written commands*": Is this really true? According to the [relevant Bash manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), the file is overwritten by the value in the list: "*If [`histappend` is] set, the history list is appended [...], rather than overwriting the file.*" The same is reflected by this SE answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6509/169543

Answer (score 8):

Building on top of what arturomp have said and in an effort to make it a bit clearer.

Assumming you have 2000-something long history..

```
~$ history
    1  sdf
    2  fghdfgjf
    3  fghfghdf
   ..  ..
 2027  78
 2028  57
 2029  yu45u
```

You can cut down what you are shown with `HISTSIZE`

```
~$ HISTSIZE=5
~$ history
 2026  546
 2027  78
 2028  56
 2029  yu45u
 2030  HISTSIZE=5
```

Now, no matter how many commands you type, only the last 5 will be recorded.

```
~$ ABC
~$ GGH
~$ GSDHFG
~$ JFDR
~$ ABSDDS
~$ AHFGHFD
<close terminal>
<open new terminal>
~$ history
    1  sdf
    2  fghdfgjf
    3  fghfghdf
   ..  ..
 2028  56
 2029  yu45u
 2030  HISTSIZE=5
 2031  GGH
 2032  GSDHFG
 2033  JFDR
 2034  ABSDDS
 2035  AHFGHFD
```

We can clearly see that our first command ("ABC") is not in the history since only the last 5 commands were recorded.

Now, the total history is stored in a file (`.bash_history`) and you can alter how long this file gets with the `HISTFILESIZE`. For example with a `2033` `HISTFILESIZE`, in my case I would have this:

```
~$ history
    1  fghfghdf
    2  gegege
    3  gege
   ..  ..
 2028  HISTSIZE=5
 2029  GGH
 2030  GSDHFG
 2031  JFDR
 2032  ABSDDS
 2033  AHFGHFD
```

Comment: What values would you recommend if I want *all* history from *all* concurrent terminals to be saved to the bash history, *forever*? In other words, save everything, always, and never delete anything.

Comment: @CivFan: Set `HISTSIZE=-1` and `HISTFILESIZE=-1`.

Comment: This is dead wrong.  Setting it to -1 will clear everything.

Comment: @BrendanByrd The `bash` man page says :

`Non-numeric values and numeric values  less  than  zero  inhibit truncation` but then I didn't have the courage to check if this is true because I don't want to loose my history :-)

Comment: @SebMa I changed my settings to `HISTSIZE='INFINITY'` and `HISTFILESIZE='ANDBEYOND'`. Since they are non-numeric they save everything. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I set `HISTSIZE` to `-1` and after logging in again `echo $HISTSIZE` gives `1000`.

Comment: Just tested, on a mac using zsh, setting these to negative or non-numeric effectively truncates at 1. My history was erased and I couldn't check my history further than 1.

Comment: FYI, this article has a similar, well-done practical demonstration of the difference between `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE`: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize