# Mac OS X (El Capitan) Terminal Command History Search Issue

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

So I have this very weird issue with Mac OS X (El Capitan) command history on both Terminal and iTerm2, using BASH

When I type

```
$ history
```

I get a list of about 6300 commands

If I type this though:

```
$ history | wc -l
```

I get "500" as the output!

Plus, when I reverse-i-search, I can only search through a few commands.

The reverse search seems to be ignoring anything beyond these 500 lines, and so does the "wc" word-count program.

In .bash_profile, I have this set:

```
HISTFILESIZE=500000
```

What's going on?

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Questions about using computers generically belong on SuperUser.com.

Comment: FYI, OS X runs a pretty old version of `bash` compared to most Unix systems.

Comment: Are you missing the `export` before the variable name? Also any chance you are overriding this with a similar value set in `.bashrc` may  be?

Comment: @Barmar, I had no idea. Will post my non-programming questions there going on!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash HISTSIZE vs. HISTFILESIZE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I feel dumb, but here goes the 'solution'.

Apparently, this is how history works in bash (`$man bash`):

> HISTSIZE     --> number of lines of command to store in history "list"
>   (memory)
>
> HISTFILESIZE --> number of lines of command to store in
>   history "file"

So I set HISTSIZE in addition to HISTFILESIZE in my .bash_profile and I'm all set now.

```
HISTFILESIZE=500000
HISTSIZE=500000
```