# How much history will be saved in iTerm2 Shell Integration's Toolbelt?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh, iterm2

**Background**:

I installed shell integration in iTerm2 and enabled saving all command history to disk so it persists between sessions (Preferences > General > Save copy/paste and command history to disk).

**Questions**:

**A)**    Is there is a limit to how much history will be stored?  Does it follow the value assigned to the HISTFILESIZE environment variable, or is it controlled some other way, or limited by default?

**B)**   The history in the toolbelt contains additional information like the working directory at the time the command was executed (printed on the cli when you option+double click the history item). Where does this information come from?

The documentation doesn't address this at all and I couldn't find any answers on google.  Does anyone know?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is an `iTerm2` documentation question. You are mixing apples and oranges. The number of past commands your shell will preserve is generally set with an environment variable (e.g. with bash `HISTFILESIZE`). What `iTerm2` does with the disk file it is saving all command history to -- is up to `iTerm2`, and has nothing to do with what the shell history file size is.

Comment: You may also be interested in [iTerm2 Leaks Everything You Hover in Your Terminal via DNS ..](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/iterm2-leaks-everything-you-hover-in-your-terminal-via-dns-requests/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin FYI: That article is already dated as the dns lookup 'feature' has been totally removed from item2.

Comment: Software moves fast given the date of the article is **September 19, 2017** (and anyone working on a system not updated to the latest (and not patched) will still be leaking...)

Comment: David C. Rankin my question is _not_ purely about the iTerm2 shell history, I already have that extended with HISTFILESIZE.  My question is specifically about the extended features of the history provided in _shell integration's toolbelt_.  As I said, I looked in the iTerm2 documentation and it does not address this question.

Comment: The history in the toolbelt contains additional information like the working directory at the time the command was executed (printed on the cli when you option+double click the history item).  I'm not sure where it gets that information and would like to know a) where that's stored and b) whether the history in the toolbelt follows HISTFILESIZE, or is controlled some other way, or is perhaps limited by default.